# statement . executeUpdate gives date truncated for column X at row 1 error

Tags: java, mysql, truncated

I'm working on a java project that tries to insert data into a mysql database through an tsv infile. When running this program it gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for
>   column 'Services' at row 1    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1402)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1317)   at
>   LogProcessing.LogReader.addDay(LogReader.java:313)    at
>   LogProcessing.LogReader.updateTables(LogReader.java:177)  at
>   LogProcessing.LogReader.start(LogReader.java:59)  at
>   LogProcessing.LogReader.main(LogReader.java:45)

The code is

```
s.executeUpdate(query);
```

where query is

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/temp/BA5770/tmp/temp.dat'INTO TABLE thisweek FIELDS TERMINATED BY '    ';
```

The weird thing is that when I copy this query and directly input it in mysql, it is accepted.

> mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/temp/BA5770/tmp/temp.dat'INTO TABLE thisweek FIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ' ';
>   Query OK, 76932 rows affected, 65535 warnings (2.44 sec)
>   Records: 76932  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 76932

The table looks like:

```
mysql> show columns from thisweek;
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| functionID | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| serverID   | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date       | date                 | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time       | time                 | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| calls      | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| meanTime   | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| WSC        | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| THM_DB2    | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DEP        | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Tandem     | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LDAP       | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PS         | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IAV        | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IMS        | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Services   | float                | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the input data looks like:

```
31  0   20111207    235900  19  0.0 -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0
32  0   20111207    235900  405 60.94   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
33  0   20111207    235900  1   32.0    24.0    14.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 8.0 0.0 24.0
34  0   20111207    235900  3   39.0    36.0    21.0    6.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 8.0 0.0 32.0
35  0   20111207    235900  27  9.44    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0    -1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

How can you say that the query is accepted at mysql console?
Look at the execution status statements :

```
Query OK, 76932 rows affected, 65535 warnings (2.44 sec)
Records: 76932 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 76932
```

For `76932` records, warnings generated are `76932`, meaning every record has some adjustable error.
Execute `show warnings` at mysql console after `load data ...` query execution and
perhaps you would see mostly `... data truncated ...` warning messages.

Working with `float` and `double` have problems in MySQL.
A workaround is to :

1. use `decimal` or `real` data types over `float` and `double` .
2. use correct floating precision in data files. But this is tedious for large data files.

There are reported bugs and workarounds at:

1. [In floating point have the same problem with FLOAT and DOUBLE. REAL
   and DECIMAL work fine.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18335)
2. [I don't know What happenig with Float and Double, but my shot is
   the ROUND made by Float...    With DECIMAL will work fine.](http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=3184)
3. [FLOAT and DOUBLE mess up with data probaly by they round
   procedures.](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?79,76131,76871)